# how to include mail gun API in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-api

I want to use Mailgun in my Rails application.

When I include through Heroku addon it display error to add credit card number though I wanted the free version.

I looked up and found this code from Mailgun. Could someone tell me how to use it?

```
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, {
    :port      => 587,
    :address   => "smtp.mailgun.org",
    :user_name => "",
    :password  => "",
  }
end

mail = Mail.deliver do
  to      'bar@example.com'
  from    'foo@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME'
  subject 'Hello'

  text_part do
    body 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness'
  end
end
```

I tried using this but it displays an error - `mailgun SSL_read: sslv3 alert bad record mac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign up with [Mailgun](https://mailgun.com/signup) and get your SMTP `username` and `password` which you would use in the mail configuration.